# Getting openLDAP working with groups and memberOf

Tags: openldap

I'm trying to get openLDAP working with users, groups and memberOf working. Does anyone know of a good tutorial that might have and example LDIF file (including users and groups) and some example ldapsearch queries to use for a sanity check that would show what groups a user is a member of? This is one of the better resources I've found: https://devopsideas.com/planning-of-ldap-dit-structure-and-config-of-overlays-access-ppolicy/.

I'm having trouble getting things to work, so it would be great to find a tutorial that is know to work so I can verify my setup. Does anyone have any good suggestions?

I'm running openLDAP in docker using this image: https://github.com/osixia/docker-openldap

I've followed the steps to add the memberOf overlay from the link listed above, and then added the a group with a user member, but an ldap query (like the one below) does not return any memberOf results.

```
ldapsearch -x -D cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com -w admin -b dc=example,dc=com -h 127.0.0.1 uid=john memberOf
```

I'd expect to see something like this:

```
dn: cn=john,ou=users,dc=example,dc=com
memberOf: cn=admingroup,ou=groups,dc=example,dc=com
```

But I just get a dn response and no memberOf info:

```
dn: cn=john,ou=users,dc=example,dc=com
```

Here is my openLDAP version info:

```
ldapsearch: @(#) $OpenLDAP: ldapsearch  (Ubuntu) (Oct 23 2018 13:01:47) $
    Debian OpenLDAP Maintainers <pkg-openldap-devel@lists.alioth.debian.org>
    (LDAP library: OpenLDAP 20445)
```

Comment: The `memberOf` overlay doesn't work retrospectively. It only works for new additions to a group.

Comment: @OokerBerry did you get this to work?